# Bash, join two tables of differing lengths using sort and join

Tags: bash, awk

I realise this is a repeat but solutions in other posts will not work for me, apologies.

I have two tables, testcut.pileup:

```
chrM    1370    T       1
chrM    1371    T       1
chrM    1372    C       1
chrM    1373    T       1
chrM    1374    A       1
```

And testcut2.pileup:

```
chrM    720     T       1
chrM    721     T       1
chrM    722     C       1
chrM    723     A       0
chrM    724     C       1
chrM    1370    T       2
chrM    1371    T       3
chrM    1372    C       4
chrM    1373    T       3
chrM    1374    A       2
```

I want to join these datasets so that the appear alongside one another. In an ideal world these would be organised by the numbers in the second columns (as below), but I would be happy just to have them alongside one another.

Desired result:

```
                             chrM    720     T       1
                             chrM    721     T       1
                             chrM    722     C       1
                             chrM    723     A       0
                             chrM    724     C       1
chrM    1370    T       1    chrM    1370    T       2
chrM    1371    T       1    chrM    1371    T       3
chrM    1372    C       1    chrM    1372    C       4
chrM    1373    T       1    chrM    1373    T       3
chrM    1374    A       1    chrM    1374    A       2
```

So far I am trying this:

```
join -j 2 <(sort -k 2 testcut.pileup) <(sort -k 2 testcut2.pileup) > join.pileup
```

But I recieve the following errors:

```
join: file 1 is not in sorted order
join: file 2 is not in sorted order
```

If I run `join` straight, the numbers in the second column are shifted:

```
chrM 1370 T 1 720 T 1
chrM 1370 T 1 721 T 1
chrM 1370 T 1 722 C 1
chrM 1370 T 1 723 A 0
chrM 1370 T 1 724 C 1
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Bash isn't the best tool for the job. I recommend doing a quick spin in Python, instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

you can make it more generic, but I hard coded for 4 fields

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$2]=$0; next} 
               {print  $2 in a?a[$2] "\t" $0:"\t\t\t\t"$0}' file{1,2} | 
  column -ts'\t'

                                chrM    720     T       1
                                chrM    721     T       1
                                chrM    722     C       1
                                chrM    723     A       0
                                chrM    724     C       1
chrM    1370    T       1       chrM    1370    T       2
chrM    1371    T       1       chrM    1371    T       3
chrM    1372    C       1       chrM    1372    C       4
chrM    1373    T       1       chrM    1373    T       3
chrM    1374    A       1       chrM    1374    A       2
```

Comment: Any chance you could advise me on what I would need to change If I wanted to apply this command across around 90 files to generate one table?

Comment: this script will not scale for 90 files, but `join` is not the right tool for more than 2 files.  Perhaps ask another question for that.

Answer (score 2):

With join, sort and bash:

```
join -j 2 <(sort -t $'\t' -k 2 testcut.pileup) <(sort -t $'\t' -k 2 testcut2.pileup) -a 2 -t $'\t' -o1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4 | sort -t $'\t' -k6n
```

I assume your field separator is one tab.

Output:

```
                                chrM    720     T       1
                                chrM    721     T       1
                                chrM    722     C       1
                                chrM    723     A       0
                                chrM    724     C       1
chrM    1370    T       1       chrM    1370    T       2
chrM    1371    T       1       chrM    1371    T       3
chrM    1372    C       1       chrM    1372    C       4
chrM    1373    T       1       chrM    1373    T       3
chrM    1374    A       1       chrM    1374    A       2
```